# How to fix code that returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this code:

```
const liked_users = promises[1];
    const disliked_users = promises[0];
    if (liked_users.length > 0 || disliked_users.length > 0){
      for(var i = 0; i < liked_users.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < disliked_users.length; j++){
          for(var k = 0; k < _USERS.length; k++){
            if(_USERS[k].useruid == liked_users[i].likedUseruid || disliked_users[j].dislikedUseruid){
              _USERS.splice(i, 1);
              i--;
              break;
            }
```

basically what is happening is that I access the firebase database and I pull out some data from my objects.

The problem comes where sometimes liked_users is going to be blank and therefore `liked_users[i].likedUseruid` will return undefined. When they are defined, the code runs fine.

How can I put in some conditional or block of code that allows it to be read in a way that accepts it can be undefined or doesn't run the code until it is defined? I can show more code if it will help.

Comment: Is it the `likedUseruid` property that is undefined or the `liked_users[i]` object itself?

Comment: From your code `liked_users` is an array. An array cannot be blank. It can be empty, or undefined, but you are already checking for length

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript if you put just variable name in `if condition` then it will check its available or not.

For example put this block

```
if(_USERS[k].useruid == liked_users[i].likedUseruid || disliked_users[j].dislikedUseruid){
....
}
```

in this

```
if(_USERS[k].useruid && liked_users[i].likedUseruid &&  disliked_users[j].dislikedUseruid){
....
}
```

The above condition will check that `_USERS[k].useruid` is available or not and will continue...

You can make condition as per your need.

I hope this will help you.